# Infopath custom list template show issue

Tags: sharepoint, infopath

When I publish my infopath custom list template. When I create a new item in the list. It is not showing the custom fields in new pop up window. Intead it is displaying the same form itself. How can I change that to pop up window with ribbon controls like Save/Close/Cancel

[image]

Comment: What version of SharePoint and InfoPath are you using?

Comment: @Nathan Sharepoint,Infopath 2010

Comment: I don't have access to SharePoint 2010 but my guess is to look into the Site/list settings as it seems that sharepoint is showing its default edit page for the list. but that is only a guess.